# Extract text from image of digital display

Tags: machine-learning

I'm looking to find some resources on creating an ML model to identify and extract text from a photo of a digital display. Possibly something similar to what apple uses for the apple pay credit card identification. The display will always have a consistent format and the individual data values will always be in the same place. So I'm assuming there would be some image manipulation involved, finding the areas for each data string and then OCR on those areas of text.

This is all very new to me but despite a lot of searching, I'm coming up short on resources or tutorials to help learn how to tackle this particular use case. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Although the wording is different, this seems a duplicate of the question that  @hxd1011 linked in his answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OCR model with TensorFlow](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248388/ocr-model-with-tensorflow)

Comment: There's no question in the text at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, and there are many steps involved to do the "Extract text from image of digital display".

My answer here can break the steps down and may be helpful for you. [OCR model with TensorFlow](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248388/ocr-model-with-tensorflow/248394#248394).